# Eve Online auth through URL query

Tags: python, api-eveonline

How can I authenticate through URL in EVE REST API?

In docs with curl, it looks like this:

```
 $ curl -i http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Please provide proper credentials.

$ curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0" -i http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

And I need something like this:

```
http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Please provide proper credentials.

http://example.com?username=admin&password=secret
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you can't as the devs have not provided this functionality.

You can always go to [/r/evetech](https://www.reddit.com/r/evetech) and ask for such a change but don't hold your breath for at least two reasons:

- Query params are used for the actual API query and having multiple classes of use just adds unnecessary complexity;
- Including auth info in the URL is not as secure as doing so in the request (header).

Out of curiosity, why do you need to be able to auth through the URL? If you are trying to do AJAX calls, most libraries will allow you to specify custom headers.